# Get value of ASP.NET hidden field from code behind using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, hiddenfield

I want to set the value of an `ASP.NET` `hidden field` with `JQuery` and then read its value from `ASP.NET` code behind.

I have this code so far but when I traced it I found out that it changes the value of `hidden field`, but `code behind` gets the previous value of `hidden field`!

Any suggestions? Thanx in advance.

ASPX:

```
<input type="hidden" id="SubmitHiddenField" name="SubmitHiddenField" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" />
```

JQuery:

```
function func() {
    if (invalid) {
        $("#<%= SubmitHiddenField.ClientID %>").val("false");
        alert("false");
    }
    else {
        $("#<%= SubmitHiddenField.ClientID %>").val("true");
        alert("true");
    }
}
```

Code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "func()", true);
string s;

if (SubmitHiddenField.Value == "true")
     s = "Yes";
else if (SubmitHiddenField.Value == "false")
     s = "No";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're checking it in the block where you've set the javascript to execute. When your if condition is executed, `func` is not actually called, as you suppose the case is.

The `func` will only be called after the `Page_Load` and other events are over an HTML is sent to the client. Only then the `func` will be executed.

So, you must only check the value after a postback. For example, you could add a button which would execute a handler in the code behind, in which you can check for the hidden field's value.

Comment: Yes. That's the problem! But how can I handle it without postback? I actually want to check if my register form values are correct and if it is then my code continues in code behind. In case the form values are not correct I just want to show that the values are not correct. I have to do it in JQ as you see the "invalid" boolean. Any better suggestions?